# How to compile a dynamic regular expression in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a simple Javascript function below that replaces the first 16 characters:

```
export const replaceFirstN = (str, n) => {
  const replace = /^.{1,16}/
  const re = new RegExp(replace)
  return str.replace(re, m => "X".repeat(m.length))
}
```

Now, I want to use the n parameter, so that I can control the no of characters that can be replaced by X. I've tried changing the replace value to:

```
replace = "/^.{1,"+n+"}/"
```

And various variations, but it won't work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`Template literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```js
const replaceFirstN = (str, n) => {
  const re = new RegExp(`^.{1,${n}}`);
  return str.replace(re, m => "X".repeat(m.length));
};

console.log(replaceFirstN("ruuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuun", 16));
console.log(replaceFirstN("apple", 2));
console.log(replaceFirstN("orange", 4));
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regex for that, if u only want to replace the first n characters of a string, u can use something like this:

```
const str = 'a sample test text to replace'

const replaceFirstN = (str = '', n) => {
  const replacement = 'X'.repeat(n);
  const rest = str.slice(n)
  return replacement + rest;
}

console.log(replaceFirstN(str, 4))
>>> 'XXXXmple test text to replace'
```

Where u append the replacement text that u build dynamically with the rest of the string.